# Unfamiliar Node.js express router format

Tags: node.js, express

I'm taking a course that provides the following code:

```
const router = express.Router();

router
  .route('/')
  .get(getBootcamps)
  .post(createBootcamp)
```

The above snippet means that GET and POST for the "/" endpoint have different routes.

I've never seen formatting like this so it's strange to me.

Why wouldn't we need separate routes for .get and .post? What is going on under the hood here? How can one be ignored?

Comment: You have to remember with NodeJS you actually create a long running instance, versus, say php, which everything is executed again with each request.  So the router command is setting up the available options for that route.  Having each request method on the same endpoint is very helpful for crud operations.  GET -> retrieve existing, POST -> create, PUT -> update existing, DELETE -> remove, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you're right. We should separate the get and post methods into separate methods rather than chaining into the same Express router.

The example code, you've written, it is also correct. But not recommended to be followed when dealing with large projects having many lines of business logic, we would make your code look heavy and difficult to read and understand. So it's better to separate.

Ps. There is no difference in output or performance, in any case, opted. At last, it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: But if they're chained, how does Express ignore one? Isn't it expecting get if I send a post ... before it reaches the post method? Where can I read about this formatting? Is there a name for it?

Comment: No.. router doesn't work that way.. when it gets GET request it just checked .get() method attached to the router. Similar case for POST request and so on.